# Elusive cards rule clarification

Tags: wow-tcg

We've just started out playing the WoWTCG that I bought recently, and I'm having trouble with one of the rules regarding a keyword.

The keyword in question is 'Elusive' and we are just not sure under what conditions this card is actually able to be damaged.

The rules (and card) state that it can't be attacked, which leads us to believe that it can't be proposed as a defender but can be targeted using abilities.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.** The [WoW TCG wiki](http://www.wowtcgwiki.org/wiki/Comprehensive_Rules#Glssary) says:

> **Elusive** - A keyword power that cards can have. It means, "This card can't be proposed as a defender."